# Tkinter "place" geometry manager not working

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I've been learning Python from an e-book. Right now I am learning about the `Tkinter` module

The book suggested running the following code. However, it does not work as it should. Any ideas why?

```py
from Tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry("200x200")

my_frame = Frame()
my_frame.pack

button1 = Button(my_frame, text = "I am at (100x150)")
button1.place(x=100, y=150)

button2 = Button(my_frame, text = "I am at (0 x 0)")
button2.place(x=0, y=0, width=100, height=50)

window.mainloop()
```

What I should get:

[image: The ideal result]

What I get:

[image: The actual result]

After adding `button1.pack()` and `button2.pack()`, I get this:

[image: The result with a different geometry manager]

Comment: please read the code and look what i get as a result(i added a picture)

Comment: It is **your job** to include all relevant information in the question. Please revise it. Consider reading e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: just forgot the () pair! yes its from the book just not copy-paste

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The smallest change I could make to make your code work is like so:

If you are going to use the Frame, you need to give it a size like so:

```
from Tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry("300x300")

# Note the change to this line
my_frame = Frame(window, width=300, height=300) 
my_frame.pack() # Note the parentheses added here

button1 = Button(my_frame, text="I am at (100x150)")
button1.place(x=100, y=150)

button2 = Button(my_frame, text="I am at (0 x 0)")
button2.place(x=0, y=0, width=100, height=50)

window.mainloop()
```

Also, the `pack()` must be a function call, so add parentheses

Comment: This works allright!
Tested and it doesnt need the "window" inside Frame() , works with width and height alone

Comment: Guys there are at least 3 correct answers!
However, I will choose this one cause it explains everything (not just telling me what to do. I really didnt know how to fill the window etc) and it's closer to what I needed!

Thanks all!

Answer (score 8):

1. don't use `place`. Learn to use `pack` or `grid`. Widgets managed by `place` won't affect the size of their containing parent. Because you don't give `my_frame` a size and because you don't pack it so that it fills the window, it's only 1 pixel tall by one pixel wide. This makes it (and the widgets inside it) effectively invisible. If you insist on using `place`,  you need to either give `my_frame` a size, or pack it with options that cause it to fill its parent.
2. `my_frame.pack` should be `my_frame.pack()` (note the trailing parenthesis)

If you're more interested in a quick fix rather than an explanation, pack `my_frame` like this:

```
my_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

That's all you need to fix your code.

Comment: An excellent explanation. Thanks a lot @BryanOakley

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call the `myframe.pack` function - you just put the function
name there, which is valid statement, but the frame was not "packed" into the
`window` (I also added fill and expand to make the frame fill the whole window, otherwise placing wouldn't work).
This should work:

```
from Tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry("200x200")

my_frame = Frame(window)
my_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

button1 = Button(my_frame, text = "I am at (100x150)")
button1.place(x=100, y=150)

button2 = Button(my_frame, text = "I am at (0 x 0)")
button2.place(x=0, y=0, width=100, height=50)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are using `pack` on your frame, and `place` on the widgets. You should not mix Tkinter layout managers; use either `pack`, *or* `grid`, *or* `place`.

If you use `place` for your widgets, then `frame.pack` does not know how large to make the frame. You have to manually provide the size of the frame to fit all its widgets, either by using the `width` and `height` parameters in the constructor, or by using `frame.place`, e.g.

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

frame = Frame(root)
frame.place(width=200, height=200)

button1 = Button(frame, text = "I am at (100x150)")
button1.place(x=100, y=150)

button2 = Button(frame, text = "I am at (0 x 0)")
button2.place(x=0, y=0, width=100, height=50)

root.mainloop()
```

But as others have already noted, I would not use `place` at all and instead rather switch to `grid` or `pack`. This way, the frame's size will automatically adapt to fit all its contents.

Comment: You are making an incorrect observation - the pack on the frame is putting the frame in the root window. The place on the buttons is putting the buttons in the frame. This is quite acceptable. While it's true you shouldn't mix grid and pack in the same containing widget, that's not what is happening here. Plus, place is a bit of a special case, and can be used along with the others in many situations.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for the heads-up. I updated my answer and hope the explanation is correct now.

Answer (score -1):

Your buttons were placed in inside the Frame `my_frame`, but the frame itself did not appear on the screen because of the missing parentheses after `my_frame.pack`. Also, the size of the frame itself should be indicated in the parentheses and be big enough to contain the buttons

In addition, you can't use place for one widget and pack for another, the placement system has to be consistent throughout your code.
Here is the code edited to work:

```
from Tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry("200x200")

my_frame = Frame(window)
my_frame.place(x=0, y=0, width=200, height=200)

button1 = Button(my_frame, text = "I am at (100x150)")
button1.place(x=100, y=150, width=100, height=50)

button2 = Button(my_frame, text = "I am at (0 x 0)")
button2.place(x=0, y=0, width=100, height=50)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: your advice is good -- using pack instead of place --  but the reasoning is flawed. `place` absolutely will make widgets appear, but only if they are in a widget that is also visible. In the case of this question, the containing window is only 1x1 so the "placed" widgets will also be invisible.

Comment: wont work! buttons now show up, however not in the right position!

Comment: I see. I'm editing this to make the buttons show at the right position, thanks!