# tkinter child widgets disappear behind the frame when frame.place() is position in a separate line

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

When I define the following function, all the other widgets that I define inside the function are appearing and are functional. I can modify the entries and get the values from them.

`

```
def frame(self):
    new_frm = tk.Frame(self.window,  width=200, 
        height=200, bg="white"
    ).place(x=self.x0, y=0)
    self.frame_list.append(new_frm)
    lbl = tk.Label(master=new_frm, relief=tk.RIDGE, 
               text=param_name, fg = "white", bg="black",   
               anchor="w", font=("Arial", 20)
   )
    lbl.place(x = self.x0, y = 0)
    self.x0 += 205
```

`

[image]

But if I change the code to below, only the frame appears and not the widgets. But, the widgets are still as functional as the first case. I wonder why this happens and how I can fix it.

`

```
def frame(self):
    new_frm = tk.Frame(self.window,  
          width=200, height=200, bg="white"
    )
    new_frm.place(x=self.x0, y=0)
    new_frm = tk.Frame(self.window,  width=200, height=200, bg=color)
    self.frame_list.append(new_frm)
    lbl = tk.Label(master=new_frm, relief=tk.RIDGE, 
               text=param_name, fg = "white", bg="black",   
               anchor="w", font=("Arial", 20)
   )
    lbl.place(x = self.x0, y = 0)
    self.x0 += 205
```

`

[image]

I want to put the new_frm into `frame_list` so I can get access to all frames later. Of course, when I use `new_frm = tk.Frame(self.window,  width=200,height=200, bg="white").place(x=self.x0, y=0)`
, the `new_frm` become a Nonetype and it doesn't work.

Update:

The solution mentioned by @Kartikeya is to use `.grid()` for widgets inside the frame. Therefore, the code must be written this way:
`

```
def frame(self):
    new_frm = tk.Frame(self.window,  
          width=200, height=200, bg="white"
    )
    new_frm.place(x=self.x0, y=0)
    new_frm = tk.Frame(self.window,  width=200, height=200, bg=color)
    self.frame_list.append(new_frm)
    lbl = tk.Label(master=new_frm, relief=tk.RIDGE, 
               text=param_name, fg = "white", bg="black",   
               anchor="w", font=("Arial", 20)
   )
    lbl.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    self.x0 += 205
```

`

Comment: How do you create *the other widgets*?  Note that `new_frm` is None in first example.

Comment: If you are using `.pack()` or `.grid()` with those child widgets, then this problems occurs because you are using `.place()` with the frame in 2nd case. You can get an idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29102873/14465779)

Comment: For your case, a quick-fix can be to do `place()` with all the child widgets of frame, and your problem will be solved

Comment: @acw1668 Yes. That is why I needed it to be in a separate line so I can make a list of frames only.

Comment: @Kartikeya Fair enough. It completely make sense the the parent covers all children. I should have thought of it. But still it is a mystery that this only occurs inside a function. When I take it out of the function, frame does not cover the children widgets. I didn't quite get your suggested quick fix. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, so better provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: No, please don't mix more than one geometry manager, like you used both `.place()` and `.grid()` . What I meant to say was, 1st- use either `.place()`, or `.pack()`, or `grid()` , any one of them. 2nd- It is usually not a good idea to use `.place()` for ordinary window and dialog layouts because then there is simply too much work to get things working as they should. Use the `pack()` or `grid()` managers for such purposes.

Comment: Now, to address your query, I'm just commenting and not answering since there is no  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), 1st- make sure the `width` and `height` of frame (i.e. 200 and 200) is big enough for contents to be visible. 2nd- In `place()` method, you can use `in_` option to put one widget inside another. Consider using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have created `new_frm` twice in second/third example:

```py
def frame(self):
    # first "new_frm"
    new_frm = tk.Frame(self.window,  
          width=200, height=200, bg="white"
    )
    new_frm.place(x=self.x0, y=0)
    # second "new_frm" which ovrrides the above one
    # and it is invisible because it is not .pack()/grid()/place()
    new_frm = tk.Frame(self.window,  width=200, height=200, bg=color)
    self.frame_list.append(new_frm)
    # label are put in the invisible "new_frm", so it is not visible as well
    lbl = tk.Label(master=new_frm, relief=tk.RIDGE, 
               text=param_name, fg = "white", bg="black",   
               anchor="w", font=("Arial", 20)
    )
    lbl.place(x = self.x0, y = 0)
    self.x0 += 205
```

Remove the second creation of `new_frm`:

```
def frame(self):
    new_frm = tk.Frame(self.window,
          width=200, height=200, bg="white"
    )
    new_frm.place(x=self.x0, y=0)
    # below line should not be called
    #new_frm = tk.Frame(self.window,  width=200, height=200, bg=color)
    self.frame_list.append(new_frm)
    lbl = tk.Label(master=new_frm, relief=tk.RIDGE,
               text=param_name, fg = "white", bg="black",
               anchor="w", font=("Arial", 20)
    )
    lbl.place(x = self.x0, y = 0)
    self.x0 += 205
```

Comment: Thank @acw1668 . It was an stupid mistake on my side.